# d3.js width of graph

Tags: d3.js

http://jsfiddle.net/BhrpA/1/embedded/result/

Why does the graph not extend the full 789px? (width of the black container div)

The SVG element is 789 but there is 100px or so of black space at the far right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your x-domain isn't set up correctly. Since arrays are 0 based, your maximum index is `length-1` not `length`.  So if you change it to:

```
x=d3.scale.linear().domain([0,data.length-1]).range([0,w])
```

You'll see that it now goes the full length as expected.